# shell prompt not showing up after running a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

as per http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0150.php i am trying to run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Program to print a text file with headers and footers

TEMP_FILE=./printfile.txt

pr $1 > $TEMP_FILE

echo -n "Print file? [y/n]: "
read
if [ "$REPLY" = "y" ]; then
    less $TEMP_FILE
fi
```

but when i run it via

```
./print_demo.bash
```

which is what it is saved as in my bin directory, it does not echo "Print file? [y/n]:" and also does not return the shell prompt. i have to ctrl^c to get it back.

Comment: You need to provide an argument to the script.  Without one, `pr` whats for standard input.

Comment: If you had correctly quoted `$1`, you would also have gotten an error message `pr: cannot open , No such file or directory`.

Comment: The other variables need to be quoted, too, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is expecting input.

```
pr "$1" > $TEMP_FILE
```

The $1 represents the first argument from the command line

```
./print_demo.bash <printable_filename_here.txt>
```